# insert dummy data to mysql fast

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, records

I have 1 function in my debug model which i want to use in order to add dummy data to my app to test its speed and such...

the problem is that it needs to add records to 2 different tables and also check for duplicates usernames etc before each record is added to db so it takes a little time...

also this procedure is repeated about $total different dummy records i want to add at once in a for loop...

for example for 100 new users i want to add it takes around 5 seconds to proceed.

is this time fine or do i need to optimize it?

what if i want to add 1000,10000 users at once?? is it possible?

**EDIT:**
Function called to insert data:

```
public function registerRandomUsers($total = 1){
    $this->load->model("misc_model");
    $this->load->model("encryption_model");
    $this->load->model("signup_model");

    for ($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++){
        $username = $this->misc_model->generateRandomString(15);
        $flag = false;
        while ($flag == false){
            if ($this->user_model->usernameExist($username)){
                $username = $this->misc_model->generateRandomString(15);
            }else{
                $flag = true;

                $password = 'Test123';
                $email = $username.'@email.com';
                $data = array(
                    'username' => $username,
                    'password' => $password,
                    'email' => $email
                );
                $this->signup_model->submitRegistration($data);
                $userdata = $this->user_model->getUserData($username, "username");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @scibuff updated post with function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not worried about having a random string as the user name, just set the `$email = 'user'.$i.'@email.com';` *(so you don't have to worry about collisions)*. The main reason this will be running slow is because you're sending a new query to the database on each iteration of the loop - it would be much much faster to generate a bulk insert string like:

```
INSERT INTO user (email,pass)
VALUES ('user1@email.com','Test123')
,      ('user2@email.com','Test123')
,      ('user3@email.com','Test123')
,      ('user4@email.com','Test123')
,      ('user5@email.com','Test123');
```

This way you can avoid the overhead of tcp traffic from sending 10000 queries to the database and have it do it all in one go.

Comment: can i append like $sql .= " ('$email'. '$pass'),"; on the main sql query

Comment: @Mikey, the only problem I see with a bulk insert statement is that the purpose of this is to test 'real world' user signups?  A bulk insert is NOT typical for signup, as those would be handled on an individual basis. **IT** would however, as you point out accelerate this script.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you're really looking for some realistic sample/test data, you should use [generatedata.com](http://www.generatedata.com/).

http://www.generatedata.com/

It's one of the best I have seen so far.

Comment: What you can do is you can either generate CSV or SQL file from generatedata.com and then if your file is CSV you can load it by using LOAD FILE, see URL below for more help.
http://blogs.digitss.com/database/mysql/export-import-csv-files-with-mysql-no-external-tool-required/

and if it's SQL you can login to mysql from command line and do following:
>> use <database>;
>> source /home/myname/Downloads/testdata.sql
and this should run all your test-data SQL insert script against selected DB and that's it you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Build your query as this

```
$conjuctions = str_repeat("('dummy@email.com','test pass'),", 20); // 20 dummy datas
$query = "INSERT INTO user (email,pass) VALUES ".substr($conjunctions,0,str_len($conjuctions).";"
                                               // ^ This is to remove the last comma
```

Comment: the thing is that i cant store same email, username and user id so they need to be different...